# Bootstrap e Gsap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gsap

I have an issue with Bootstrap. In short, if I try to create a container and a row to align the two columns, it doesn't work, the image disappears and everything gets messed up. For now I have fixed it like this to have it intact on the desktop version, but how can I get around this problem in the mobile version?

```js
gsap.utils.toArray(".section-parallax .parallax-content").forEach((section, i) => {
  const heightDiff = section.offsetHeight - section.parentElement.offsetHeight;

  gsap.fromTo(section, {
    y: -heightDiff
  }, {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: section.parentElement,
      scrub: true
    },
    y: 0,
    ease: "none"
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.spacer {
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.page-header {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.section-parallax {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax-content {
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 190%;
}

.section-mood-image {
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 70vh;
}

.p1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
}

.p2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.p3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.p3 a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="spacer"></div>
<section class="page-header d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="contacts">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <p class="p1">Example</p>
    <p class="p2">Test1</p>
    <p class="p3"><a href="#">Test2</a></p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 section-parallax">
    <div class="parallax-content" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597098494674-36c3813a65f3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ');"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.3/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-7Au1ULjlT8PP1Ygs6mDZh9NuQD0A5prSrAUiPHMXpU6g3UMd8qesVnhug5X4RoDr35x5upNpx0A6Sisz1LSTXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question (in English). Please update the demo above to show your problem. No need to send us to other sites.

Comment: Tips: Bootstrap already does the reset you've included in your CSS. Also, spacer divs are an outdated practice. Use margin, padding, flexbox gap, etc. instead of extra markup.